# CSS Menu Horizontal the menu lost

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing an application with ASP.Net MVC4, jquery 1.9, CSS 2.1 
I have a problem with the horizontal menu. 
When I show a form with a jquery component, or any button is lost as the menu can make it appear to the front as you can see in the pictures: 
the correct menu:
[image]

menu horizontal problem:
[image]

how you can see the first option of the submenu is lost (Figure 2)
How I can resolve this problem?

**Update add code css**

```
.menu, .menu ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 2em;
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu > li {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.menu > li:first {
  margin-left:0px!important;
}

.menu > li > a {
  background: #ffc850;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  margin: 0;
  width: auto;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #3366CC;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

div.box {
  position:absolute;
  z-index: -2;
  background-color: #ffc850;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
}   

li.pull-down {
  padding-right:0px;
}

li.pull-down > a {
  background-image: url('/content/images/darrow.png');
  background-position: 96% 75%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

li.right-menu > a {
  background-image: url('/content/images/rarrow.png');
  background-position: 97% 45%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.menu a.selected {
  background-color: #75CDD2;    
  border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 4px;
}

.menu li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  display:none;
  width: auto;
  top: 2em;
  background-color: #ffc850;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3366CC;   
  border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 4px;
}

.menu li ul a {
  width: 180px;    
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 7px 20px;    
}

.menu li ul li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu ul ul {
  top: auto;
}

.menu li ul ul {
  left: 200px;
}

.menu-item-selected > a {
  background-color: #fff;    
  font-weight: bold;
  -moz-opacity: .70;
  filter: alpha(opacity=55);
  opacity: .70;
}

.menu-item-selected > a:hover {    
  color: #3366CC !important;
}
```

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words, but leave a lot of guessing when it comes to code.

Comment: It looks like the horizontal menu bar is absolutely positioned with a higher z-index than the pull down menu... really need to see the code and css...

Comment: @Diodeus I added the code css

Comment: @MarcAudet I added the code css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.menu > li {
  margin-left: 0px;
  z-index: 9999999
}
```

I am adding 999999 as i want to give the max z-index value , you can adjust accordingly. the other menu has apparently higher z-index than your menu.